# Fix Unusual Boolean Variable Behavior

Tags: log-messages

I have this `javascript` code, that calls a `php` function `myid_save_ellipse_elements`

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'?q=myid_save_ellipse_elements',
    data:{ 
        'ellipse': true
    }
}).done(function(status){                   
});
```

Below is the php function:

```
function myid_save_ellipse_elements(){
   $ellipse = $_POST['ellipse'];        
   watchdog('ellipse', print_r($ellipse, true));
   $fields = array('ellipse_id_side' => $ellipse);
   watchdog('fields', print_r($fields, true));
}
```

After performing the code above, the watchdog message logs two message. The first message is `true`, and the second message is `Array([ellipse_id_side] => )`.

The second logs no value. why is it?

Comment: Works fine for me - both entries are in the log, both have `true` in them. Check your server config for weirdness around processing POST vars maybe?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of ellipse has value as [TRUE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921708/377342). Use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php). Check example below:

```
  $ellipse = $_POST['ellipse'];        
  watchdog('ellipse', print_r($ellipse, true));
  $fields = array('ellipse_id_side' => $ellipse);
  watchdog('fields', var_export($fields, true));
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference? I can log arrays with `true` values fine using `print_r`. It would be a pretty major bug in php if `print_r` returned an empty string for boolean values n an array (it doesn't by the way, just double-checked). The SO post you linked to says `false` returns an empty string, while `true` returns `1`. So the OP should be seeing `Array([ellipse_id_side] => (int) 1` if that's to be believed?

Comment: @Clive, I tested the code in my local now, and it does log both values. Your comment in question seems correct, it might be something at server configuration level.

Comment: Yeah, agree with that